# Installing kernel_sas for Jupyter onto OpenShift

Tags: sas, openshift, jupyter

I'm trying to add `kernel_sas` to my Jupyter Notebook installation so I've added it to my `requirements.txt` before building my image,

#### requirement.txt

`kernel_sas==2.1.0`

but it seems that the package is unknown in the `conda` registry.

[image]

I've been looking to the anaconda registry via their web interface, and it seems to have one : 
https://anaconda.org/danielfrg/sas_kernel

Is there a way to install it via `requirements.txt` or directly via github releases to my OpenShift container? I've tried with a `dash` or `underscore`, same result.

Comment: That points to the SAS software kernel on GitHub, the README file has installation instructions. https://github.com/sassoftware/sas_kernel

Comment: There's nothing about OpenShift in the documentation, but thanks for highlighting that link.

Comment: You are mistaking anaconda default channel for user channel. What you point to is the channel for the user `danielfrg`.